# In Eclipse RCP, is it possible to show both icon and label for a toolbar item?

Tags: eclipse-rcp, eclipse-plugin

If the `icon` and the `label` are both defined in the `plugin.xml` then only the `icon` will be displayed but if the `icon` attribute is removed, then only the `label` is displayed.

Is it possible to have both visible?

**Icon:**

```xml
<toolbar id="my.toolbar">
  <command commandId="my.Command"
    icon="import.gif" id="commandID"
    label="Import Config" style="push">
  </command>
</toolbar>
```

**Label:**

```xml
<toolbar id="my.toolbar">
  <command commandId="my.Command"
    label="Import Config" style="push">
  </command>
</toolbar>
```

Comment: What extension point is this?

Comment: @greg-449 <extension point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please use `mode` option with `FORCE_TEXT` value:

> mode - For actions appearing in a toolbar, FORCE_TEXT will show text
>   even if there is an icon. See ActionContribuitonItem.

http://help.eclipse.org/helios/nftopic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_ui_viewActions.html